# Print values from database separated by coma except last one

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to print values from database separated by comma, except last one.

```
$result = getValue($projectNo,$proc[$y]);
if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid queryyyy: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}   
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{  
    $procLeader = $row['proc_leader'];
    $column_procLeader .= $procLeader." (leader), ";
    echo $column_procLeader;
}
```

How can I check if value is last one in the row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP separate entries with a comma, except last entry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964108/php-separate-entries-with-a-comma-except-last-entry)

Comment: i just use rtrim to remove the last comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set counter & then check 1st entry & change ','position....

```
$result = getValue($projectNo,$proc[$y]);
if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid queryyyy: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}   
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{  
    if($i==0)
    {
      $procLeader = $row['proc_leader'];
      $column_procLeader .= $procLeader." (leader)";
    } 
    else
    {
      $procLeader = $row['proc_leader'];
      $column_procLeader .= ", ".$procLeader." (leader)";
    }
    echo $column_procLeader;
    $i++;
}
```